# Arduino "unknown device" error on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, arduino, usb, device-driver

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, I'm new to arduino and I searched for my question here on ST and found similar but outdated queries that didn't help me so I might as well help others who might be having the same problem.

The very first time I connected arduino to my W7 laptop, it worked like a charm, installed new device drivers successfully, uploaded my sketch (which still continues to run every time its powered). I checked device manager and it showed the arduino under COM/LPT ports.

Then, after disconnecting the arduino and reconnecting, it no longer shows a COM/LPT section and instead shows an unknown device under USB. Every time I've tried uninstalling driver and reconnecting, it keeps giving me a driver installation failed error.

Googling for the issue told me to "update drivers" manually using the .inf provided with the Arduino installation through device manager, but when I tried that, it says the drivers aren't compatible with Windows x64.

Another tip from an arduino forum user told me to copy the arduino.inf into C:/Windows/inf, but that didn't solve the problem either

Any ideas?

Comment: There are many types of Arduinos.  Could you provide a link to the specific one you have?  What sketch did you upload?  Can you post the code?

Comment: Also, you might try here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/